# Font redistribution with @font-face

Tags: css, html, font-face

We all know that fonts can be embedded in web pages now with the `@font-face` CSS directive. In order to do this, the font to be embedded must be placed in a readable directory on the web server. This means that any suitably motivated individual can download the font and use it on their own machine.

Does this mean that embedding a font counts as redistributing it? If I were to purchase a font, can I embed it and use it in a web page?

**EDIT**
I'm asking all this because I'm considering embedding Helvetica in a web page.

Comment: IANAL, but I think it *does* count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only embed a font using @font-face when web-use is allowed in the font's EULA. Some fonts come with a separate license for use on the web.

If you're worried about people stealing your @font-face files, you could use a service such as Typekit which lets you upload your web fonts and embed them using their service.

Comment: Mikos is right, you have to make sure the font you want to use can be licensed for use on the web. If it can, but you are worried about it being easily accessible you can do as Mikos suggested and use a service such as Typekit, or you can Base64 encode your font and include it in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very difficult question - it depends on the country you live in, I think.
You paid for the font, so you're allowed to use it. I never heard that there was a conflict because of that.

The be 100% sure, I suggest to ask the creator of the font.

Comment: What if the font you are considering embedding happens to be Helvetica?